# Escape all special characters in printf()

Tags: c++, c, char, escaping, printf

Is there an easy way to escape all special characters in the `printf()` function?

The reason why I would like to know how to do this is because I am printing a number of characters which may include special characters such as the null character (`\0`) and the beep character and I just want to see the contents of the string.

**Currently I am using the following code**

It works for null characters. What would be the easiest way to escape all special characters?

```
int length;
char* data = GetData( length ); // Fills the length as reference

for( int i = 0;  i < length;  i++ )
{
    char c = data[ i ];
    printf( "%c", ( c == 0  ?  '\\0'  :  data[ i ] ) );
}
```

Comment: Does printing the char directly not just work? You would only need to escape the char literal... which I don't really see why you need to use.

Comment: currently `'\\0'` is two chars: the char `'\\'` and the char `'0'`. Does this actually print `\0` to the terminal for `c == 0`?

Comment: '\\0' is an integer with value 23600 (0x5C30) or 12380 (0x305C), whatever byte order the compiler fancies. So the %c will either print \ or 0. The byte order of the machine is not tied to the choice the compiler made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `'\\0'` is a two-character literal, which should really be a two-character string. As for printing all special characters as escape code, you need some more code:

```
switch (data[i])
{
case '\0':
    printf("\\0");
    break;
case '\n':
    printf("\\n");
    break;

/* Etc. */

default:
    /* Now comes the "hard" part, because not all characters here
     * are actually printable
     */
    if (isprint(data[i]))
        printf("%c", data[i]);  /* Printable character, print it as usual */
    else
        printf("\\x%02hhx", (unsigned char) data[i]); /* Non-printable character, print as hex value */

    break;
}
```

Comment: The isprint function takes an unsigned character as parameter. It crashes using a signed char.

Also, is there a shorter way to print the non-printable character? The hexadecimal value is very long.

Comment: @MichielPater Normal character *all* have values below 256, at least on all system with 8-bit `char` types. You mean you have character in the extended ASCII range (i.e. above 127)? Also see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint), where it states "The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF."

Comment: @MichielPater And if the hexadecimal numbers are long, are you sure that `data` is an array (or a pointer to) `char`? You're not using `wchar_t`? Can you please give an example of the output?

Comment: Characters such as '\xffffff93F' are printed. It adds all these f's which I don't like.

Comment: @MichielPater Then once again I ask, are you not using `wchar_t` characters? Because the only way to get those kind of number would be if you are *not* using `char`. If you print e.g. `sizeof(data[i])` what do you get then?

Comment: In my question I am explicitly using a variable of type `char`. It prints `1`.

Comment: @MichielPater Yes, and then you should not get these weird values, unless you're on a platform where `char` is *not* eight bits (they are unusual but they do exist). Can you please update your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Because right now I can't see why this shouldn't work. Also, regarding your first comment, `isprint` actually takes an `int` as argument, and should handle the whole 8-bit extended ASCII alphabet on a normal PC (unless you are on some other platform using a non-conforming compiler).

Comment: The problem came from printing the char as a char instead of an unsigned char. Thank you :)

Comment: If you use a `char` the compiler is free to treat as `unsigned char` or `signed char`. If it chose to consider it `signed` then when calling `isprint()` with a char which highest bit is set (i.e. 128 to 255), the value will be convertet to `int` but **sign extended** which mean that every bit left will be set to 1. That's where the FF come from. When you use `is...` functions you have to typecast them before. As these functions are generally implemented as table lookups in a 256 byte table, indexing with negative number will result in `undefined behaviour`.

Comment: @tristopia The weird thing is that the number given by the OP is not *only* sign extended, it seems to be a sign extension of `0x93f` which is definitely not a `char` (signed or unsigned).

Comment: I don't see how that would be even possible. There is probably something missing from Michiel Pater's presented code. The number he gives '\xffffff93F' seems to be imho 2 separate characters. The following F being uppercase and printed because isprint() said it could. And the other char 0x93 sign extended and isprint() having reached whatever byte before the table decided it was not printable and displayed it as hex value.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `isprint` library function to determine if the character is printable:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if (isprint(data[i]))
  printf(" %c", data[i]);    // prints character
else
  printf(" %d", data[i]);    // prints code value for character
```

Comment: The isprint function takes an unsigned character as parameter. It crashes using a signed char.

Comment: @MichielPater: not according to the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 7.4.1.8; the prototype is `int isprint(int c);` If it's crashing on a plain old signed `char`, then there's either a problem in the implementation or in the way it's being called.

Comment: No, signed char's are sign extended. Which means that codepoints between 128 and 255 will give `undefined behaviour`. The compiler is free to consider `char` as `signed` or as `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

In case code needs to write with *no* ambiguity, using C syntax:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void EscapePrint(int ch) {
  // Delete or adjust these 2 arrays per code's goals
  // All simple-escape-sequence C11 6.4.4.4
  static const char *escapev = "\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\"\'\?\\";
  static const char *escapec = "abtnvfr\"\'\?\\";
  char *p = strchr(escapev, ch);
  if (p && *p) {
    printf("\\%c", escapec[p - escapev]);
  } else if (isprint(ch)) {
    fputc(ch, stdout);
  } else {
    // Use octal as hex is problematic reading back
    printf("\\%03o", ch);
  }
}

void EscapePrints(const char *data, int length) {
  while (length-- > 0) {
    EscapePrint((unsigned char) *data++);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, code could

```
void EscapePrint(char sch) {
  int ch = (unsigned char) sch;
  ...
}
void EscapePrints(const char *data, int length) {
  while (length-- > 0) {
    EscapePrint(*data++);
  }
}
```

To use a hexadecimal-escape-sequence or a shorten octal-escape-sequence, code needs to insure that the *next* character does not create ambiguity.  That complication does not occur in the above code as it uses 3-digit octal-escape-sequences. Amended code would be something like:

```
  } else {
    if ((ch == 0) && (nextch < '0' || nextch > '7')) {
      fputs("\\0", stdout);
    }
    else if (!isxdigit((unsigned char) nextch)) {
      printf("\\x%X", ch);
    }
    else {
      // Use octal as hex is problematic reading back
      printf("\\%03o", ch);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


/* Converts a buffer of specified lenth to
 * ASCII representation as it was a C string literal.
 * Returns how much bytes from source was processed
 * (ideally ret == src_sz)
 */
int binbuf_to_escaped_C_literal(const char *src_buf, size_t src_sz, char *dst_str, size_t dst_sz)
{
    const char *src = src_buf;
    char *dst = dst_str;

    while (src < src_buf + src_sz)
    {
        if (*src == '\\')
        {
            *dst++ = '\\';
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
        else if (isprint(*src))
        {
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
        else
        {
            switch(*src)
            {
                case '\n':
                    *dst++ = '\\';
                    *dst++ = 'n';
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    *dst++ = '\\';
                    *dst++ = 'r';
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    *dst++ = '\\';
                    *dst++ = 't';
                    break;
                case '\0':
                    *dst++ = '\\';
                    *dst++ = '0';
                    break;
                default:
                    sprintf(dst, "0x%x", *src);
                    dst += 4;
            }
            src++;
        }

        // next iteration requires up to 5 chars in dst buffer, for ex.  "0xab\0"
        if (dst > (dst_str + dst_sz - 5)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    *dst = '\0';

    return src - src_buf;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char binbuf[] = "strange \n\r\t\0\0\0\0\0\\\\ string";
    size_t sz = sizeof(binbuf) - 1; // drop trailing nul terminator

    char escaped[128];

    if (binbuf_to_escaped_C_literal(binbuf, sz, escaped, sizeof(escaped)) != sz) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Destination string buffer is too small\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Escaped: %s\n", escaped);

    // $ ./escape-binary-buf                                          //
    // Escaped: strange \n\r\t\0\0\0\0\0\\\\ string                   //

    return 0;
}
```