# how to escape values for writing a CSV file using C language

Tags: c, csv

I am working on a project to write data as CSV file.
how to escape values for writing a CSV file using C language.

```
void writeToFile(struct raDataStructure data)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("result.data", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "%s,", data.long);
    fprintf(fp, "%s,", data.lat);
    fprintf(fp, "%s,", data.city);
    fprintf(fp, "%d,", data.pobox);
    fprintf(fp, "%s,", data.bio);
    fprintf(fp, "%d,", data.bNumber);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

the filed `data.bio` may contain any character including comma, quote and slashes. How can I escape it before writing to file to make a valid csv file.

Comment: By write a function that transformes a string into en escaped string. Show what you have tried.

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "\"%s\",", data.bio);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: almost, but if the string contains '"' they must be repeated, e.g. [Hello "World"] should be ["Hello ""World"""] once escaped.

Comment: any one have a pre built function for this?

Comment: @fSazy: maybe you find some source code out there, but there is no standard library AFAIK. But you can write it yourself, it's not that difficult. It's mainly about duplucating every '"' in the string to be escaped and enclosing it into '"'.

Comment: There's no standard function for that.

Comment: find character in string you want to escape, put escaped instead and go on until no more is left. Try implementing this and come back to us if you will have problems.

Comment: This similar answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150946/escape-all-special-characters-in-printf/22152332#22152332

Comment: Neither slashes nor backslashes need special treatment in CSV; only double quotes and commas do.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a good starting place. Note that you need to `free()` the value it returns when done with it.

```
char* escapeCSV(char* in) {
  int in_len = strlen(in);
  char *out_buf = malloc(in_len*2+3);
  int out_idx = 0;
  int in_idx = 0;

  out_buf[out_idx++] = '"';
  for(in_idx=0; in_idx < in_len; in_idx++) {
    if(in[in_idx] == '"') {
      out_buf[out_idx++] = '"';
      out_buf[out_idx++] = '"';
    } else {
      out_buf[out_idx++] = in[in_idx];
    }
  }
  out_buf[out_idx++] = '"';
  out_buf[out_idx++] = 0;
  return out_buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### csv.h

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: csv.h,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 2.1 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2012/11/01 23:45:19 $
@(#)Purpose:        Scanner for Comma Separated Variable (CSV) Data
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Origin:         Kernighan & Pike, 'The Practice of Programming'
*/

#ifndef CSV_H
#define CSV_H

#include <stdio.h>

extern char  *csvgetline(FILE *ifp);    /* Read next input line */
extern char  *csvgetfield(size_t n);    /* Return field n */
extern size_t csvnfield(void);          /* Return number of fields */
extern void   csvreset(void);           /* Release space used by CSV */

extern int    csvputfield(FILE *ofp, const char *field);
extern int    csvputline(FILE *ofp, char **fields, int nfields);
extern void   csvseteol(const char *eol);

#endif /* CSV_H */
```

#### csv.c

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: csv.c,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 2.2 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2013/01/28 03:28:55 $
@(#)Purpose:        Scanner for Comma Separated Variable (CSV) Data
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Origin:         Kernighan & Pike, 'The Practice of Programming'
*/

/* See RFC 4180 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) */

#include "csv.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { NOMEM = -2 };

static char *line = 0;      /* Input line */
static char *sline = 0;     /* Split line */
static size_t maxline = 0;  /* Size of line[] and sline[] */
static char **field = 0;    /* Field pointers */
static size_t maxfield = 0; /* Size of field[] */
static size_t nfield = 0;   /* Number of fields */

static char fieldsep[]= ",";    /* Field separator characters */
static char fieldquote = '"';   /* Quote character */

static char eolstr[8] = "\n";

void csvreset(void)
{
    free(line);
    free(sline);
    free(field);
    line = 0;
    sline = 0;
    field = 0;
    maxline = maxfield = nfield = 0;
}

static int endofline(FILE *ifp, int c)
{
    int eol = (c == '\r' || c == '\n');
    if (c == '\r')
    {
        c = getc(ifp);
        if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ungetc(c, ifp);
    }
    return(eol);
}

static char *advquoted(char *p)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    for (i = j = 0; p[j] != '\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        if (p[j] == fieldquote && p[++j] != fieldquote)
        {
            size_t k = strcspn(p+j, fieldsep);
            memmove(p+i, p+j, k);
            i += k;
            j += k;
            break;
        }
        p[i] = p[j];
    }
    p[i] = '\0';
    return(p + j);
}

static int split(void)
{
    char *p;
    char **newf;
    char *sepp;
    int sepc;

    nfield = 0;
    if (line[0] == '\0')
        return(0);
    strcpy(sline, line);
    p = sline;

    do
    {
        if (nfield >= maxfield)
        {
            maxfield *= 2;
            newf = (char **)realloc(field, maxfield * sizeof(field[0]));
            if (newf == 0)
                return NOMEM;
            field = newf;
        }
        if (*p == fieldquote)
            sepp = advquoted(++p);
        else
            sepp = p + strcspn(p, fieldsep);
        sepc = sepp[0];
        sepp[0] = '\0';
        field[nfield++] = p;
        p = sepp + 1;
    } while (sepc == ',');

    return(nfield);
}

char *csvgetline(FILE *ifp)
{
    size_t i;
    int    c;

    if (line == NULL)
    {
        /* Allocate on first call */
        maxline = maxfield = 1;
        line = (char *)malloc(maxline);     /*=C++=*/
        sline = (char *)malloc(maxline);    /*=C++-*/
        field = (char **)malloc(maxfield*sizeof(field[0])); /*=C++=*/
        if (line == NULL || sline == NULL || field == NULL)
        {
            csvreset();
            return(NULL);   /* out of memory */
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; (c = getc(ifp)) != EOF && !endofline(ifp, c); i++)
    {
        if (i >= maxline - 1)
        {
            char  *newl;
            char  *news;
            maxline *= 2;
            newl = (char *)realloc(line, maxline);  /*=C++=*/
            news = (char *)realloc(sline, maxline); /*=C++-*/
            if (newl == NULL || news == NULL)
            {
                csvreset();
                return(NULL);   /* out of memory */
            }
            line = newl;
            sline = news;
        }
        line[i] = c;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    if (split() == NOMEM)
    {
        csvreset();
        return(NULL);
    }
    return((c == EOF && i == 0) ? NULL : line);
}


char *csvgetfield(size_t n)
{
    if (n >= nfield)
        return(0);
    return(field[n]);
}

size_t csvnfield(void)
{
    return(nfield);
}

int csvputfield(FILE *ofp, const char *ofield)
{
    const char escapes[] = "\",\r\n";
    if (strpbrk(ofield, escapes) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(ofield) + 2;
        const char *pos = ofield;
        while ((pos = strchr(pos, '"')) != 0)
        {
            len++;
            pos++;
        }
        char *space = malloc(len+1);
        if (space == 0)
            return EOF;
        char *cpy = space;
        pos = ofield;
        *cpy++ = '"';
        char c;
        while ((c = *pos++) != '\0')
        {
            if (c == '"')
                *cpy++ = c;
            *cpy++ = c;
        }
        *cpy++ = '"';
        *cpy = '\0';
        int rc = fputs(space, ofp);
        free(space);
        return rc;
    }
    else
        return fputs(ofield, ofp);
}

int csvputline(FILE *ofp, char **fields, int nfields)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nfields; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            putc(',', ofp);
        if (csvputfield(ofp, fields[i]) == EOF)
            return EOF;
    }
    return(fputs(eolstr, ofp));
}

void csvseteol(const char *eol)
{
    size_t nbytes = strlen(eol);
    if (nbytes >= sizeof(eolstr))
        nbytes = sizeof(eolstr) - 1;
    memmove(eolstr, eol, nbytes);
    eolstr[nbytes] = '\0';
}

#ifdef TEST

int main(void)
{
    char *in_line;

    while ((in_line = csvgetline(stdin)) != 0)
    {
        size_t n = csvnfield();
        char *fields[n];        /* C99 VLA */
        printf("line = '%s'\n", in_line);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("field[%zu] = '%s'\n", i, csvgetfield(i));
            printf("field[%zu] = [", i);
            csvputfield(stdout, csvgetfield(i));
            fputs("]\n", stdout);
            fields[i] = csvgetfield(i);
        }
        printf("fields[0..%zu] = ", n-1);
        csvputline(stdout, fields, n);
    }

    return(0);
}

#endif /* TEST */
```

Answer (score 0):

To print using a C-like escape sequence:

```
void EscapePrint_CSV(FILE *outf, int ch) {
  // Delete or adjust these 2 arrays per code's goals
  // All simple-escape-sequence C11 6.4.4.4 and , for CSV
  static const char *escapev = ",\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\"\'\?\\";
  static const char *escapec = ",abtnvfr\"\'\?\\";
  char *p = strchr(escapev, ch);
  if (p && *p) {
    return fprintf(outf, "\\%c", escapec[p - escapev]);
  if (isprint(ch)) {
    return fputc(ch, outf);
  // Use octal as hex is problematic reading back
  return fprintf(outf, "\\%03o", ch);
  }
}

void EscapePrints_CSV(FILE *outf, const char *s) {
  int retval = 0;
  retval = EscapePrint_CSV(outf, '\"');
  if (retval) return retval;
  while (*s) {
    retval = EscapePrint_CSV(outf, *s++);
    if (retval) return retval;
  }
  return EscapePrint_CSV(outf, '\"');
}
```

The particulars of how a CSV handles an embedded `','` vary.  Some escape them.

Others quote an entire string like `"Hello, World"`.  Then escaping the `"` becomes an issue.  Some escape a `'\"'` by simply repeating it `""`.

YMMV.