# How can I get a text file into a string but whith the "\n" in C?

Tags: c, string, file

I have a text file and I need to get it in a string but it has to show the "\n"

For example, this is hello.txt:

Hello,

World

And I need the string to return: "Hello,\nWorld\n"

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: read file character by character and check if character is \n if so applend \\n to the string

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could read the file one character at a time.

Test each character that you read to see if it is a newline character ('\n').
If it is not a newline character, print the character that was read.
If it is a newline character, print "\n".

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Test each `char` of the string.  Once code starts using `"\n"` to show `'\n'`, then one needs to escape `'\\'`.  To print a string like "Hello World", code may want to escape `'\"'` to distinguish if `quotes` are part of the print-out.  If the string contains non-printable or non-ASCII `char`, what then?  Maybe print an octal escape sequence like `\377`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void EscapePrint(int ch) {
  // Delete or adjust these 2 arrays per code's goals
  // All simple-escape-sequence C11 6.4.4.4
  static const char *escapev = "\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\"\'\?\\";
  static const char *escapec = "abtnvfr\"\'\?\\";
  char *p = strchr(escapev, ch);
  if (p && *p) {
    printf("\\%c", escapec[p - escapev]);
  } else if (isprint(ch)) {
    fputc(ch, stdout);
  } else {
    // Use octal as hex is problematic reading back
    printf("\\%03o", ch);
  }
}
```

More detail: [Escape all special characters in printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150946/escape-all-special-characters-in-printf/22152332#22152332)