# Locating and translating escape sequences to other values

Tags: c, io, tr

What would you use to check for escape sequenced values?
I have two inputs arg1 and arg2. If you enter ab\t xyz into the arguments. And then if you were to type in "ab\t" into the input you would get "xyz" as output.
I hope this makes sense and im really stuck at the escape character handling. Currently the code works for all except for when there are escape chars or if one argument is longer than the other.

```
it is a c code we wrote on our own the plan is to make a custom tr() function
void tr_str(char s[], char news[]){
    int c;
    size_t k =0;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            for(k=0; k < strlen(s);k++)
            {                   
                if(c == s[k])
                {
                    c = news[k];
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for use to view

Comment: is this c code or shell code using tr?

Comment: it is a c code we wrote on our own the plan is to make a custom tr() function

Comment: I will add the code to the question.

Comment: ok - what does the debugger say is happening

Comment: how do you input  \t? from the keyboard? piped in from a file? does c ever end up having \t in it?

Comment: You use standard input with command line. The arguments are entered at ./a (arguments).
I have a way to read everything in main but the problem is that currently it takes the  '\' as a separate char from 't' for example.

Comment: After `c = news[k];` add `break;` to prevent any chance that `c` is translated back again further along the array.

Comment: [Escape all special characters in printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150946/escape-all-special-characters-in-printf) or [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150946/escape-all-special-characters-in-printf/22152332#22152332) may help

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I have interpreted escape chars in two ways. First the `tab` character is in the array `s[]`, and secondly I trap the `\` char in the escape sequence of `\t` and use a second pair of arrays to translate the escape sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) { 
    char s[]="abcd\t";
    char news[]="ABCD!";
    char e[]="t";
    char newe[]="!";
    int c, k, esc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (esc) {
            for (k=strlen(e)-1; k>=0; k--) {
                if (c == e[k]) {
                    c = newe[k];
                    break;
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
            esc = 0;
        }
        else if (c == '\\') {
            esc = 1;
        } 
        else {
            for (k=strlen(s)-1; k>=0; k--) {
                if (c == s[k]) {
                    c = news[k];
                    break;
                }
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program input (the spaces result from the `tab` key)

```
a\tz      d
```

Program output:

```
A!z!D
```

Comment: i suspect the OP problem is trying to enter the \t character into the args when running it from the command line- ie tr "abcd\t" "xyxpq", he seems to be saying that he ends up with \ and t

Comment: @pm100 answer improved, a similar way can be used if the input comes from a program argument, but OP uses `getchar()`.